# Reserva de asientos en Java

Tags: java

tengo un proyecto de la universidad me pusieron a hacer reservacion de asientos. Tengo una duda como hago por si mi usuario digita asiento(fila 2 columna 3) por ejemplo que salga que ese asiento no se puede ocupar.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Cinema{ //Inicio

```
public static void main(String args[]){ // Inicio

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int c= 1 , fila, columna;
    int asiento [][] = new int [4][40];

    while(c <= 160){ // Inicio while

        System.out.println("Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-4)");
        fila = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Favor ingresar el numero de columna(1-40)");
        columna = sc.nextInt();

        if(asiento[fila - 1] [columna - 1] == 0)
        { // If
            asiento[fila - 1][columna - 1] = 1;
            c++;
            System.out.println("Reserva exitosa");
        } // If
        else
            System.out.println("Asiento ocupado");
    } // Fin while
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    { // For
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 40 ; j++)
        { // For
            System.out.println(asiento[i][j]+ "\t");
        } // For
        System.out.println();
    } // For
} // Fin
```

} // Fin

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la pregunta... ¿Quieres que el programa muestre un mensaje cuando alguien intenta reservar un asiento ya reservado con anterioridad? Si es eso lo que buscas, puedes considerar crear una clase ```Asiento``` que tenga los atributos ```fila, columna``` y un atributo ```estaOcupado``` (con sus setters y getters respectivos). Entonces, antes de reservar, chequeas si el asiento está ocupado y en base a eso dejas que el usuario reserve o no.

Comment: Es que en cierto espacio del teatro no puedo registrar a nadie, es para pasillos. Como hago para decirle usted esta reservando un pasillo no puede hacerlo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas un poco más de contexto en tu pregunta para tener más claridad sobre el asunto y poder ayudarte mejor. Lee, por favor, [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por otro lado, por lo que dices y veo en el código, asumo que estás considerando **toda** la sala como una matriz bidimensional en lugar de sólo considerar en dicha matriz los asientos. ¿Qué elementos de la matriz creada deberían ser los pasillos? Eso puede darte una idea de cómo referirte a los mismos de forma matemática con los índices ```i``` y ```j```.

Comment: Disculpa la columna 5 y 16 no se pueden tomar, son pasillos.

Comment: 1. dibuja una grilla de m filas x n columnas. 2 elige las filas y columnas que serán pasillos y colorealas. 3. cada selección marca la casilla correspondiente en la grilla. 4. si la selección apunta a un sitio marcado se reporta como nula. 5, el usuario siempre puede ver las posiciones disponibles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completando la primera respuesta, te aporto la siguiente solución **simple y básica**:

Teniendo en cuenta que tú pides que los elementos de la columna 5 y de la columna 16 no puedan ser reservados porque representan pasillos, puedes implementar lo que [Jasc24](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/157003/jasc24) aporta: asignarles a estos puestos un valor que represente un pasillo.

Digamos, por ejemplo, que el código de números que usaremos para guiarnos será el siguiente:

**0** : Asiento libre.

**1** : Asiento reservado.

**2** : Pasillo.

Ahora, debemos crear las variables necesarias (las mismas que tú creaste), agregando la inicialización de los valores para los asientos libres y los pasillos. Esto lo logramos de la forma:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<40; j++)
      if(j==5 || j==16) asiento[i][j] = 2;
      else asiento[i][j] = 0;
```

Aquí, asignamos el valor **2** a aquellos asientos cuyo valor de columna sea **5 ó 16**, y le asignamos el valor **0** al resto (todos los asientos comienzan sin reserva).

Luego, te hago una observación: en tu bucle `while` sólo incrementas el valor de `c` cuando logras hacer una reserva exitosa. El problema está en que el bucle seguirá ejecutándose mientras `c<=160` y, si observas detenidamente, la cantidad de elementos total de tu matriz bidimensional que representa al cine **contando los pasillos** es 4*40 = 160, y como nunca podrás reservar un pasillo, la variable `c` nunca llegará al valor 160 y, por consiguiente, nunca saldrás del bucle `while` por más que hayas reservado todos los asientos posibles.

Para corregir esto, podemos implementar una estructura de bucle `while` de la siguiente forma:

```
while(c<=160)
{
   //Reserva...

   c++;
}
```

De esta forma, nos garantizamos que la variable `c` llegará en algún momento al valor 160 y podremos salir del bucle `while`.

## Pero... ¿Qué pasa con la validación de datos?

¿Qué pasa si el usuario ingresa un valor no válido de filas o columnas? Es decir, cómo tiene que comportarse el programa si el usuario ingresa el valor de fila **0** y el valor de columna **58**, o el valor de fila **6** y el valor de columna **-3**?

Para solucionar esto, podemos hacer que cada vez que el usuario ingrese un valor, el programa corrobore si está dentro de los valores admitidos. Si es así, el programa continúa. De lo contrario, pide nuevamente el valor erróneo e insiste hasta que el usuario ingrese un valor válido.

Por ejemplo, para las filas, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
System.out.print("Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-4): ");
            
fila = sc.nextInt();
            
while(fila<1 || fila>4)
{
   System.out.print("Valor de fila no válido. Favor ingresar el numero de fila nuevamente (1-4): ");
                
   fila = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Esto asegura que mientras el usuario ingrese un valor entero que no esté en el intervalo [1,4], el programa volverá a insistir que el usuario ingrese nuevamente el valor.
Cabe aclarar que si quisiéramos hacer una validación de datos rigurosa, deberíamos ver si lo que el usuario ingresa no es una letra o un símbolo... Pero esto es una corroboración básica.

Haremos lo mismo para las columnas.

Una vez que tanto la fila como la columna haya sido ingresada, pasaremos a verificar el estado en el que se encuentra el asiento elegido por el usuario: si el asiento está ocupado, devolverá un '1'; si está libre, devolverá un '0', y si es un pasillo, devolverá '2'.

Esto lo haremos de una forma similar a la que implementaste tú, agregando el caso del pasillo:

```
if(asiento[fila-1][columna-1]==0)
{
   asiento[fila-1][columna-1] = 1;
   System.out.println("Reserva exitosa.\n");
}
else if(asiento[fila-1][columna-1]==1) System.out.println("Asiento ocupado.\n");
else System.out.println("Imposible reservación. La ubicación ingresada corresponde a un pasillo.\n");

c++;
```

Sin importar lo que suceda (reservación, asiento ocupado o elección de pasillo), incrementaremos el valor de `c`. Logrando así que `c` pueda llegar hasta el valor 160.

El código completo lo dejo aquí abajo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cinema
{
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        int c= 1,fila,columna;
        int asiento [][] = new int [4][40];
        
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<40; j++)
                if(j==5 || j==16) asiento[i][j] = 2;
                else asiento[i][j] = 0;
    
        while(c<=160)
        {
            System.out.print("Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-4): ");
            
            fila = sc.nextInt();
            
            while(fila<1 || fila>4)
            {
                System.out.print("Valor de fila no válido. Favor ingresar el numero de fila nuevamente (1-4): ");
                
                fila = sc.nextInt();
            }
            
            System.out.print("Favor ingresar el numero de columna (1-40): ");
            
            columna = sc.nextInt();
            
            while(columna<1 || columna>40)
            {
                System.out.print("Valor de columna no válido. Favor ingresar el numero de columna nuevamente (1-40): ");
                
                columna = sc.nextInt();
            }
    
            if(asiento[fila-1][columna-1]==0)
            {
                asiento[fila-1][columna-1] = 1;
                System.out.println("Reserva exitosa.\n");
            }
            else if(asiento[fila-1][columna-1]==1) System.out.println("Asiento ocupado.\n");
            else System.out.println("Imposible reservación. La ubicación ingresada corresponde a un pasillo.\n");
        
            c++;
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;  j<40; j++)
                System.out.println(asiento[i][j]+ "\t");
            
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

## Algo más..

Tú solicitaste que las columnas 5 y 16 sean las columnas que representen a los pasillos.

Si el usuario ingresa el valor **5** ó **16**, verás que el programa dejará hacer la reserva, pero esto es porque en la corroboración utilizas los índices `fila-1` y `columna-1`. Si el usuario ingresa **6** ó **17**, ahí sí mostrará el mensaje de que estamos en una posición de pasillo.

Si deseas modificarlo, basta con editar la asignación del valor **2** para las columnas que desees.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos. Funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer tu matriz y asignar valores a las casillas que serían consideradas pasillos, una vez asignados los pasillos, simplemente comparar con las posiciones dadas por el usuario y si esta coincide con la coordenada de un pasillo, mostrar el mensaje.

**Digamos que toda la 6 columna es pasillo, entonces harías algo como esto, para asignarla como pasillo:**

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int c=0;c<40;c++){
        if(c==5){
            //Asignar valor que corresponde a pasillo
        }
    }
}
```

Lo anterior es solo para la asignación de los pasillos, ya solo restaría agregar las comparaciones que muestren si está en las coordenadas de un pasillo.

**OJO: si solo asignarás pasillos a columnas específicas, solamente pregunta al usuario si la coordenada de la columna, es igual a la de algún pasillo, es decir si asignaste la 6 columna, el índice sería 5, pues estos funcionan en base 0**

Espero que esto te de un aire de lo que necesitas para resolver tu problema.

Comment: en el caso de que quisiera modificar el texto de la butaca 1,3,5.. etc para que estuvieran deshabilitadas. Que se le podría hacer?

Answer (score 1):

He aquí la solución a tu pequeño problema.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Omar
 *
 */
public class Cinema { // Inicio

    //Constantes 
    private static final String NUMERO_FILA = "Número de fila (1-4)";
    private static final String NUMERO_COLUMNA = "Número de columna (1-40)";
    private static final String CONSTANTE_INPUT ="Favor ingresar el ";
    private static final String CONSTANTE_NO_VALIDO="Valor no válido, ";
    private static int asiento[][] = new int[4][40]; //Declaramos el array para poder usar en diferentes metodos 

    public static void main(String args[]) { // Inicio
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int c = 1, fila, columna;

        for (int i = 0; i < 160; i++) { // Inicio for
            fila = obtenerInformacion(NUMERO_FILA, sc, 'F'); //Obtenemos la fila 
            columna = obtenerInformacion(NUMERO_COLUMNA, sc, 'C');//Obtenemos la columna

            if (i>0 && !verificarDisponibilidad(fila, columna)) { //La validación de si el asiento esta reservado, lo haremos despues del primmer registro
                System.out.println("El asiento de la fila: " + fila + " y la columna:" + columna + " esta ocupado");
            }else { //Si no existe asiento ocupado se procede a ingresar.
                asiento[fila -1][columna -1] = 1; //- 1 ya que el array inicializa en 0 
                System.out.println("Reserva exitosa");              
            }
        } // Fin while

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // For
            for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) { // For
                System.out.println(asiento[i][j] + "\t");
            } // For
        } // For
        System.exit(0);
    } // Fin

    //Metodo para obtener la fila o columna desde el teclado
    private static int obtenerInformacion(String constant, Scanner sc, char bandera) {
        int entero = 0;

        while (entero == 0) {
            System.out.println(CONSTANTE_INPUT + constant);
            entero = sc.nextInt();
            //Esto es para que no se ingrese valor erroneo.
            if ((bandera == 'F' && entero > 4) || (bandera == 'C' && entero > 40)) {
                System.out.println(CONSTANTE_NO_VALIDO + constant);
                entero = 0;
            }
        }
        return entero;
    }

    //Metodo para validar asiento disponible
    private static boolean verificarDisponibilidad(int aFila, int aColumna) {
        aFila= aFila-1; //-1 ya que el array inicializa en 0
        aColumna=aColumna -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < asiento.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < asiento[x].length; y++) {               
                if (asiento[x][y]>0 && (x == aFila && y == aColumna)) {
                    return false; //Se retorna false en caso de que el asiento este ocupado.
                }
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }

} // Fin
```